# Hiding the grouping header when filtering grouped contents with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering, grouping, momentjs

I have a grouped list of contents which is grouped based on date:

> **2014/7/21**
>
> - 100: 2014/7/21 05:30
> - 101: 2014/7/21 05:30
>
> **2014/7/22**
>
> - 102: 2014/7/22 05:30
> - 103: 2014/7/22 05:30
> - 104: 2014/7/22 05:30
>
> **2014/7/23**
>
> - 105: 2014/7/23 05:30
> - 106: 2014/7/23 05:30
> - 107: 2014/7/23 05:30
>
> **2014/7/24**
>
> - 108: 2014/7/24 05:30

I also have a selection filter that allows user to select the ID (100~ 108). Let's say if the user select 101 and then the filtered content will look like this:

> **2014/7/21**
>
> - 101: 2014/7/21 05:30
>
> **2014/7/22**
>
> **2014/7/23**
>
> **2014/7/24**

Therefore, I'm wondering is there's a way to dynamically hide/show the header when applying filter?

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4D3Jw/5/

**View**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller='GroupController'>

        <select class="col-md-12" ng-model="IDFilterSelect">
            <option value="" selected>All</option>
            <option ng-repeat="option_ID in options" value="{{option_ID.id}}">{{option_ID.id}}</option>
        </select>

        <ul ng-repeat="log in logs">
            <h2><b>{{log.dateheader | moment:'YYYY/M/D'}}</b></h2>                

            <li ng-repeat="item in log.items | IDFilter: IDFilterSelect" >
                <div>
                    <span><b>{{item.id}}:</b>  </span>
                    <span>{{item.datetime | moment:'YYYY/M/D hh:mm' }}</span>    
                    <br /> 
                </div>  
            </li>       
        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('GroupController', function ($scope) {

    var myLogs = [{
        id: 100,
        datetime: "2014-07-21T17:30:00"

    }, {
        id: 101,
        datetime: "2014-07-21T17:30:00"
    }, {
        id: 102,
        datetime: "2014-07-22T17:30:00"
    }, {
        id: 103,
        datetime: "2014-07-22T17:30:00"            
    }, {
        id: 104,
        datetime: "2014-07-22T17:30:00"
    }, {
        id: 105,
                  datetime: "2014-07-23T17:30:00"
    }, {
        id: 106,
                  datetime: "2014-07-23T17:30:00"
    }, {
        id: 107,
                  datetime: "2014-07-23T17:30:00"
    }, {
        id: 108,
                  datetime: "2014-07-24T17:30:00"
    }];

    $scope.options = _.uniq(myLogs, 'id');        

    $scope.logs = _.chain(myLogs).groupBy(function (log) {
        var moment_log_datetime = moment(log.datetime, "YYYY-MM-DD");
        return (moment_log_datetime.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    }).pairs().map(function (currentItem) {

        return _.object(_.zip(["dateheader", "items"], currentItem));
    }).value();


})


app.filter('moment', function () {
    return function (dateString, format) {
        return moment(dateString).format(format);
    };
});

app.filter('IDFilter', [function () {
    return function (myLogs, ID) {
        if (!angular.isUndefined(ID) && !angular.isUndefined(myLogs)) {
            if(ID != ""){
            var logs = _.filter(myLogs, function (log) { return log.id == ID });

                return logs;
            }
            else{
              return myLogs;  
            }
        }
        else {
            return myLogs;
        }


    };

} ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put an `ng-show="log.items.length"` in the `h2` tag. It will be hidden when `log.items.length` is 0 (falsy value). [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: `ng-show="(log.items | IDFilter: IDFilterSelect).length > 0"`. And far better on the `<ul>` tag rather than just the `<h2>` one.

Comment: Good call on the `<ul>` tag and filter. I didn't notice you were filtering the collection!